# I've been trying to make this @media code work for 30 minutes already but I still can't find an answer

Tags: html, css

```css
div.klase {
  background-color: aqua;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media screen and (max-width:500px;
) {
  .klase {
    background-color: pink;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="klase"></div>
```

First of all sorry if this question might be dumb , I'm trying to change its .klase color to pink when it is smaller than 500px . But it doesn't seem to work that way even though it's almost similiar to  the other examples of media queries. Appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: `div.klase` is more specific than `.klase` so your media block will not work. You also need to remove the `;` after `500px`

Comment: Going off of @Turnip 's comment, specifying an element before a class like "div.klase" isn't necessary for most situations.

Answer (score 2):

It works with specificity. Try this way

```css
div.klase {
  background-color: aqua;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media screen and (max-width:500px) {
  div.klase {
    background-color: pink;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this

```css
.klase {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color:aqua;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .klase {
    background-color:pink;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="klase"></div>
```